# Export HTML for offline use (Pyecharts, Python)

Tags: python, html, dashboard, interactive

Let's say I am trying to export the following chart below:

```py
from pyecharts.charts import Bar
from pyecharts import options as opts

def create_bar_chart():
    x_data = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
    y_data = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
    bar = (
        Bar()
        .add_xaxis(x_data)
        .add_yaxis("Series A", y_data)
        .set_global_opts(title_opts=opts.TitleOpts(title="Bar Chart Example"))
    )

    return bar
```

The problem is that I can't export the file for offline use (without internet connection). Please offer some advice. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save it as html like this:

```py
chart = create_bar_chart()
chart.render("bar_chart.html")
```

This will create a local HTML file `bar_chart.html` that will display your chart.  However, since this relies on external (online) javascript, if you don't have internet when you use your browser to open this HTML file, it will not display as desired.

If you peek inside the generated HTML file, you'll see that in the header, it loads in the following javascript file:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="https://assets.pyecharts.org/assets/v5/echarts.min.js">
</script>
```

In a pinch, you can download this javascript and store it locally, say at some place on your machine `local/path/to/echarts.min.js`, if you need a fully offline version.  Then just edit the HTML to replace the above snippet with the following:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="local/path/to/echarts.min.js">
</script>
```

(Also consider, as an alternative to downloading a JS file: cache it, using a [service worker](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-your-app-work-offline-with-the-power-of-javascript-685d968bcfbb/))

Comment: Thanks. I have embed the echarts.min.js into the HTML. In that way there will be no need of file. But thanking to your comment I switched in that direction. In practice it is the same as your proposed solution. Appreciate a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **render function** (https://pyecharts.org/#/en-us/render_images) and add `.html` as the extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the js at first and rewrite the global config of pyecharts:

```py
import pyecharts
pyecharts.globals.CurrentConfig.ONLINE_HOST = "path/to/local/echart.min.js"
```

Or you can just modified the source code, which is the variable `DEFAULT_HOST` in class `_OnlineHost` at `pyecharts/globals.py` in the third package director. But this is not recommanded.